# How to display RSS feed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, rss

In an attempt to avoid Facebook and still have a newsfeed to read my news, I was wondering if it is possible to display RSS feed on Ubuntu 18.04? Or in any other way get to the samme result without giant companies track my data.

Comment: What research have you done on this topic?

Comment: I found this: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-rss-readers-available-in-ubuntu.html and saw this some time ago. Is a must see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=8&v=Dv6t21xXogY